# Why Yii2 user identity is null in controller init() method?

Tags: php, yii2

In my controller I have this code:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    Yii::$app->user->identity // NULL ???
}

public function actionIndex()
{
    Yii::$app->user->identity // Identity object!
}
```

In my config:

```
...'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        'defaultRoles' => ['guest'],
    ],

 'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\modules\user\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'enableSession' => false,
        'loginUrl' => null,
    ], ...
```

It is possible to get identity on init?

Comment: Try to use `beforeAction()`

Answer (score 1):

I just tested getting user identity in `init()` method of controller and it works fine.

`null` is returned when user is guest (not logged-in), so check that.

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    var_dump(Yii::$app->user->isGuest, Yii::$app->user->identity);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if a user is log in using

```
Yii::$app->user->isGuest
```

if it returns true it means that the current user is guest i.e. the user has not been logged in and you can opt to redirect the user to your login page.

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
      if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return true;
        }
        return $this->redirect(['/user/security/login']);//redirect to user login page 
}
```

On the same note there is an awesome  yii2 extension that has the following User management features.

1. Registration with an optional confirmation per mail
2. Registration via social networks
3. Password recovery
4. Account and profile management
5. Console commands
6. User management interface

https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user

Comment: How it's different from my answer, except mentioning of extension?